# Efficiently Handle a Large Number of Individual Files in Python

Tags: python, dataset, large-language-model

I'm facing a challenging problem and I'm seeking advice on the most efficient solution. I'm in the process of generating a dataset containing 540,000 examples, which are organized into 100 separate directories, each containing approximately 5,400 examples. The structure looks like this:

```
├── dir1
│   ├── file11.csv
│   ├── file12.csv
│   └── ...
├── dir2
│   ├── file21.csv
│   ├── file22.csv
│   └── ...
├── ...
└── dir99
```

Each of these files is in CSV format. Currently, my code reads each individual file, sends a request to a server with information from the CSV, and saves the response back into the file. I've created a bash script to launch a Python process for each of the 100 directories, but it's still taking a considerable amount of time.

The server is a self hosted LLM which takes a prompt with the information from the CSV.

I'm looking for suggestions on how to optimize both the file I/O and the processing.

This is my code:

```
def split_and_truncate(input_string, max_tokens=512):
    # Split the input string into tokens using space as a delimiter
    #print(F"Input String {input_string}")
    tokens = input_string.split()
    #print(F"Tokens {tokens}")

    # Check if the token count exceeds the specified limit
    if len(tokens) > max_tokens:
        # Truncate the string by joining the first max_tokens tokens with spaces
        truncated_string = ' '.join(tokens[:max_tokens])
    else:
        truncated_string = input_string

    return truncated_string

def execute_prompt(prompt):
    print(prompt)
    args = {"batch": [prompt]}
    request = requests.post(F"http://{node}:5000", json=args)
    results = request.json()
    print(results["data"][0])
    response = results["data"][0]
    return response

for dir in sorted_list:
    for filename in os.listdir(os.path.join(subdir, dir)):
        print(filename)
        file_name_vic = f'context_{mode_vic}_{filename}.json'
        context_file_vic = F'{subdir}/{dir}/{filename}/{file_name_vic}'

        summary_path = f"{subdir}/{dir}/{filename}/summary_{filename}.csv"
        
        if not os.path.exists(context_file_vic):
            with open(output_filename, "w") as output_file:
                output_file.write(f"{filename}\n")
            continue

        if os.path.exists(summary_path):
            continue
        df_vic = pd.read_json(context_file_vic, orient="records", dtype=object)

        df_vic = df_vic[['X', 'Y', 'text']]
        df_vic["summary"] = np.nan


        for index, row in df_vic.iterrows():
            print(F"length of input {len(row['text'].split())}")

            input_string = split_and_truncate(row['text'])


            prompt= f"""
            ### Instruction:
            Different instructions

            ### Input: 
            Reads the input:  "{input_string}"

            ### Output: """
            
            if pd.isna(df_vic.at[index, "summary"]):
                response2 = execute_prompt(prompt)
                df_vic.at[index, "summary"] = response2


            df_vic.to_csv(summary_path, index=False)
```

Comment: There are plenty of crucial questions this brings up; what is the average size of each CSV file and the total size of all files combined? How much available RAM and computing resources do you have for this task? Are there any constraints on memory usage or time limit? Is it necessary to save the response in the same file? Is it essential to maintain the current file and directory structure, or can the data be restructured, for example, by consolidating it into a single DataFrame? Also, are you open to using efficient storage formats for persisting the DataFrame to disk if needed?

Comment: Each file is less than 1mb, I have 100GB of RAM available, and I have a time limit of 48 hours before my jobs need to end. And I need to maintain that structure because I have multiple experiments with different settings and LLM's. And can you explain your last question?

Comment: What I meant was that if you're open to restructuring the data storage, you can consider consolidating the smaller files into fewer (but larger) files, but in a way that preserves the structure. Probably not a big deal though. Also, 540k * 1MB is over 500 GB, so it won't all fit in RAM as-is, but it's helpful information to know. I'm not skilled enough to know exactly the best way to optimize this but that clarification should be useful for anyone else looking to answer this.